# Best way to present a list of items in a video presentation

Tags: video, presentation

I need to present a list of 10 items in a video presentation (text & audio).

First approach: Display items one by one following the audio that narrates. What you hear is what you see, with items displayed one by one, first at the top then going to the bottom. (That means first items will be visible longer than the last, which is shown only for the time is narrated.)

Second approach: Display all the items at once, then highlight each item while you hear it from the audio narration (only one highlighted at each moment).

Third approach: ??? Any suggestions?

What is the best approach to present this list of 10 items in this video presentation?

(It's a website introduction video)

Comment: Can you clarify as to the purpose for this video? You mentioned website intro. Is it for promoting a product on a landing page? A more in-depth How-to video? You'll want different approaches for the two. An promo intro with 10 items is likely far too lengthy.

Comment: @nightning its the categories of the products the site sells. example: in our site you will find all the fruits you can make delicious juices: oranges, bananas, strawberries....(10 items)

Comment: I prefer first approach. Second one is boring.